How do i build a sensitive spring loaded, weight bearing platform?
I would like to build a humane rat trap that doesn’t involve using bait on a snap rat trap. I would build a 5 sided cage out of 12 or 16 gauge wire. The 6th side would be built out of a light composite/ veneer..a door that flips down. Presently i have a wire mesh side/ door that the clever rat avoids stepping on to retrieve the bait that’s attached to a rat snap trap which flips up and flings the rat into the cage.
If there was a way to spring load the side/ door so that when the rat steps on the side that’s laying on the ground covered with some soil, his weight would trigger a mechanism that flings him into the cage.
Any ideas?

https://youtu.be/pq97_JoB47g?si=cVFPdLI7KJrLBeAN

Bucket trap. No idea what humane means though. do you eat electrocuted chickens like I (and a lot of humanity) do?
